# Do I need immutable Map in this case?

Tags: scala

I'm attempting to maintain a List of Document classes within an immutable Map :

```
object DocumentModel extends App{

  case class Document(title : String , text : String)


  val documentMap = Map[org.joda.time.DateTime , Document]()


  def addDocument(d : Document) :  Map[org.joda.time.DateTime , Document]= {
    documentMap + (new org.joda.time.DateTime -> d)
  }

  addDocument(Document("title" , "text"))

  println("size is "+addDocument(Document("title" , "text")).size);


}
```

When access `documentMap` its size is consistently one as each time the returned Map in method `addDocument` is just appending element same immutable collection.

How can append to immutable Map and return its values or do I need to use immutable Map ?

Update :

An option is to use :

```
object DocumentModel extends App{

  case class Document(title : String , text : String)

  var id = Map[org.joda.time.DateTime , Document]()

  def addDocument(d : Document) :  Map[org.joda.time.DateTime , Document]= {
    id = id + (new org.joda.time.DateTime -> d)

    id
  }

  addDocument(Document("title" , "text"))

  println("size is "+addDocument(Document("title" , "text")).size);
  println("size is "+addDocument(Document("title" , "text")).size);


}
```

But this is not thread safe

Comment: Immutability itself implies that it cannot be mutated means it can't be modified. in your case you are just returning a new map. use either var and immutable map OR val and mutable map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code the method `addDocument` does not change the `documentMap` member at all, it just always returns a new map with one element. The member `documentMap` stays empty.

If you want to keep a map of all added documents, you have two options:

either use a mutable map in a `val` member `documentMap`, or use a `var` member `documentMap` with an immutable map.

Which approach you chose depends on how you intend to use the map. If you will never return the whole map, then using a mutable map is ok. If however you return  the map from some public methods, then I'd chose the `var`-immutable approach.

Because your method `addDocument` returns the map, I'd use the `var`-immutable approach as mohit suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I am under the impression that you want to create mutable objects (`DocumentModel`) by composing immutable objects (`Map`), and this won't work.

The first solution, as you found out, is to use a mutable `Map` for `documentMap`. You will therefore get a mutable `DocumentModel`.

```
val documentMap = mutable.Map[org.joda.time.DateTime , Document]()
```

You will be able to use your mutable `DocumentModel` the following way :

```
val docs = DocumentModel()
docs.addDocument("title1", "text1")
docs.addDocument("title2", "text2")
docs.addDocument("title3", "text3")
```

The second solution is to return a new `DocumentModel` in your `addDocument` method :

```
def addDocument(d : Document) :  Map[org.joda.time.DateTime , Document]= {
    val newDocumentMap = documentMap + (new org.joda.time.DateTime -> d)
    DocumentModel(newDocumentMap)
}
```

You will therefore get a immutable `DocumentModel`, which is used differently :

```
val docs0 = DocumentModel()
val docs1 = docs0.addDocument("title1", "text1")
val docs2 = docs1.addDocument("title2", "text2")
val docs3 = docs2.addDocument("title3", "text3")
```

or

```
val docs = DocumentModel().addDocument("title1", "text1")
                          .addDocument("title2", "text2")
                          .addDocument("title3", "text3")
```

Comment: for second solution does this mean DocumentModel needs an apply method ? : DocumentModel(newDocumentMap)

Comment: You need to have a constructor which takes an immutable map as argument